# AWS Cognito Password Expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there any way by which we can enforce password expiration and reuse old passwords policies in AWS Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cognito password policy doesn't support this.

You can specify length, type of characters, but that's pretty much it. Look over 
 [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-policies.html) for more info.

You can use [AdminResetUserPassword API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html) to force a password invalidation.

Comment: Thanks Radu Diță

Comment: Is there any way of forcing password expiration in cognito userpool like iam users in AWS?

Comment: Updated my answer, in short, use AdminResetUserPassword to reset the password